# Create a symlink to a file in kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, sysfs

I am trying to create a symbolic link to a file in a Linux kernel module. With the following code, I have created a directory in `sys/kernel` and then created a file in that directory:

```
// Create the base directory in sys/kernel
    if (!(pmd_kobjSysKernelDir =
            kobject_create_and_add(PMD_DRIVER_NAME, kernel_kobj)))
        return -ENODEV;

    if ((retVal = sysfs_create_file(
            pmd_kobjSysKernelDir, &dev_attr_sysfs.attr)))
    {
        dev_err(&client->dev,
                "couldn't create %s file \n", dev_attr_sysfs.attr.name);
        return retVal;
    }
```

Now I am trying to create a symbolic link to the file, that is represented by the `dev_attr_sysfs` structure. The problem is, I only found `sysfs_create_link` function, which seems to be able to create only directory symbolic links (I think). Is there a way to use it in order to create a symbolic link to a file? If not, is there any other dedicated function?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call `sys_symlink` or `sys_symlinkat`. Or it is better to look in implementation file `fs/namei.c`.